# Remove chart padding

Tags: swiftui, ios-charts

I've put this graph view in my SwiftUI app, the code is setup so that the graph should take all the available space but for some reason it doesn't and there is this little bit of annoying **padding** (Blue lines in the image) is there any way I can remove it?

*I'm sure the problem isn't in my SwiftUI code because if I replace the Graph with any other view it doesn't have any padding at all, so I think this is solvable in the Graph code (UIViewRepresentable) not in my SwiftUI code*

[image]

Comment: It might be not padding... would you show your SwiftUI code using this graph (graph code itself is not needed for now)?

Comment: try chartView.minOffset = 0

Comment: thanks aiwiguna, it was the minOffset

Answer (score 0):

One way to find where padding comes from is to [examine the view hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html) and see the names of the views on either side of where the padding occurs.

Beyond that, it's hard to say from just the posted details.